# Hyper-V 2012 R2 cluster functional level missing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-cluster

I have a 4 node Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Hyper-V cluster that was built from scratch. Everything is working well but when I tried adding a Windows Server 2016 node to the cluster it gave "Different OS level" error. When I type `Get-Cluster | select ClusterFunctionalLevel` there is no level returned. I tried the command `Update-ClusterFunctionalLevel` and it said the command is not recognized.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server 2016 box open fail over cluster manager and do a "connect to cluster". That should work, you can not add the 2016 server from a 2012r2 server, not sure why, but thats what microsoft's documentation says. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/cluster-operating-system-rolling-upgrade

Comment: Using the 2016 server cluster manager, I was able to join the 2016 node to the 2012 r2 cluster. It won't let me migrate any of the vm's to the 2016 node. Tried using both the 2012 & 2016 cluster manager.

Comment: Update: Typo in network settings on 2016 node. Corrected and all is working correctly. Thanks for the assistance!